# What are the differences between http and ftp

Tags: http, ftp

We can transfer file from one system to other by ftp. but also we can upload file from http protocol. I mean we can achieve transfer of file from one location to other by both way.so how they differ from each other. Please explain.

Comment: One starts with `f` and the other starts with `ht`? Did you try googling for this information? it's quite trivial to find the RFC's definining both protocols.

Comment: @ Marc B: Yes i searched on internet i want the mechanism that is used to transfer.

Comment: you're basically asking "what's the difference between english and french". they both do similar things, but sound different and get there via different paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FTP:**

1. FTP much faster for single large file transfers and is used for file transfers with authentication.
2. FTP provides no meta-data for files.
3. FTP has limited support for pipelining.
4. FTP resume download support is limited(for 2GB files).

**HTTP:**

1. HTTP is faster in transferring multiple small files and is used for web pages with/without authentication.
2. HTTP provides meta-data for files such as Content-Types, etc.
3. HTTP supports pipelining. It means that a client can ask for the next transfer already before the previous one has ended, which thus allows multiple documents to get sent without a round-trip delay between the documents, and TCP packets are thus optimized for transfer speed.
4. HTTP supports more advanced byte ranges, so better resume downloading capabilities.

This answer is based on this article,

https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP** -- The protocol powering the web.
**FTP** -- An old and insecure protocol for transferring files.

Answer (score 0):

**Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)** is a protocol used in networking. When you type any web address in your web browser, your browser acts as a client, and the computer having the requested information acts as a server. When client requests for any information from the server, it uses HTTP protocol to do so. The server responds back to the client after the request completes. The response comes in the form of web page which you see just after typing the web address and press “Enter”.